# How to run ng serve as local user using angular cli

Tags: angular

Tried ng serve under local account but getting broccoli plugin error.Is there any way to run ng serve without admin rights in local account under windows

Comment: what `ng --version` gives you ?

Comment: 1.0.0-beta.21 version